How to efficiently keep a stable frame rate video stream in a PyQt application?
I am developing a PyQt (PySide6) application that needs to display and store multiple camera streams at the same time. The display of the camera streams goes well; however, storing these streams seems to slow down the application significantly up to a point where the GUI doesn't work fluently anymore.
I have a minimal working example using a stub to demonstrate how my code currently works. However, given that it is a minimal working example, it will not visibly slow down.
import sys
from time import sleep

import av
import numpy as np
import pyqtgraph as pg
from PySide6.QtCore import QThread, Signal, Slot, Qt
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QHBoxLayout, QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QPushButton, QGroupBox


class RGBCameraStub(QThread):

    newFrame = Signal(np.ndarray)

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.killSwitch = True

    def stop(self):
        self.killSwitch = False
        self.quit()
        self.wait()

    def run(self):
        self.killSwitch = True
        while self.killSwitch:
            self.newFrame.emit((np.random.rand(1456, 1080, 3) * 255).astype(np.uint8))
            sleep((20 + int(np.random.rand() * 30))/ 1000)


class VideoWriter(QThread):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.output_container = av.open('output_video.mkv', mode='w')
        self.stream = self.output_container.add_stream('ffv1', rate=None)
        self.stream.width = 1456
        self.stream.height = 1080
        self.stream.pix_fmt = 'yuv420p'

    @Slot(np.ndarray)
    def addFrame(self, frame: np.ndarray):
        av_frame = av.VideoFrame.from_ndarray(frame, format='rgb24')
        av_frame.pts = None # Leave emtpy for auto-handling - variable framerate?
        for packet in self.stream.encode(av_frame):
            self.output_container.mux(packet)

    def stop(self):
        self.output_container.close()
        self.quit()
        self.wait()

    def run(self):
        self.exec()


class VideoBox(QGroupBox):

    def __init__(self, title):
        super().__init__(title=title)
        self.createLayout()
        self.videoWidget.setImage((np.random.rand(1456, 1080, 3) * 255).astype(np.uint8))

    def createLayout(self):
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.videoWidget = pg.RawImageWidget()
        layout.addWidget(self.videoWidget)
        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.setStyleSheet("""QGroupBox {
            border: 1px solid #494B4F;
            margin-top: 8px;
            min-width: 180px;
            min-height: 180px;
            padding: 2px 0px 0px 0px;
            }
        QGroupBox::title {
            color: #aeb0b8;
            subcontrol-origin: margin;
            subcontrol-position: top left;
            left: 20px;
            padding: 0 8px;
        }""")

    def setImage(self, data: np.ndarray):
        self.videoWidget.setImage(data)

class MainWindow(QWidget):

    closeSignal = Signal()

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setGeometry(0, 0, 900, 720)
        self.createLayout()

    def createLayout(self):
        self.vimbaImage = VideoBox("RGB")
        self.info = self.infoLayout()

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.vimbaImage)
        layout.addWidget(self.info)
        self.setLayout(layout)

        self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_StyledBackground, True)
        self.setStyleSheet("MainWindow { background-color: #1e1f22; }")

    def infoLayout(self):
        widget = QWidget()
        layout = QVBoxLayout()

        rgbButtonWidget = QWidget()
        buttonLayout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.connectButton = QPushButton('Connect', parent=self)
        self.disconnectButton = QPushButton('Disconnect', parent=self)
        buttonLayout.addWidget(self.connectButton)
        buttonLayout.addWidget(self.disconnectButton)
        buttonLayout.addStretch()
        rgbButtonWidget.setLayout(buttonLayout)
        layout.addWidget(rgbButtonWidget)

        widget.setLayout(layout)
        return widget

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        self.closeSignal.emit()
        event.accept()



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    rgbCamera = RGBCameraStub()
    videoWriter = VideoWriter()
    videoWriter.start()

    main_window = MainWindow()

    # Button connections
    main_window.connectButton.clicked.connect(rgbCamera.start)
    main_window.disconnectButton.clicked.connect(rgbCamera.stop)
    # main_window.disconnectButton.clicked.connect(videoWriter.stop)

    # Display frames
    rgbCamera.newFrame.connect(main_window.vimbaImage.setImage)

    # Write frame to file
    rgbCamera.newFrame.connect(videoWriter.addFrame)

    # Close application
    main_window.closeSignal.connect(rgbCamera.stop)
    main_window.closeSignal.connect(videoWriter.stop)

    main_window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())


My question(s) therefore are:

How can I increase the performance of the VideoWriter? I am currently adding frame by frame as soon as the camera thread provides a new frame. Maybe this is not the best approach?
The frame rate of the camera is not completely stable, I therefore set av_frame.pts = None but maybe this is also not the approach to take?
With code as is, the resulting media file quickly blows up in size, is there a way of dealing with this without quality loss?

As a side note, I currently use the PyAV wrapper for the FFmpeg library, however I am open to other suggestions.

your GUI shouldn't suffer, if you successfully separated all the video compression into its own thread. perhaps consider setting a lower priority on that thread.

ffmpeg/pyav are perfectly fine receiving single frames. that is the API. there is nothing to be gained by batching, nor is there even a way to do it. maybe find out if the video compression itself is using multithreading (enable/disable that by setting the number of threads, try both)

ffv1 is lossless and intra-only. it's going to emit high-bitrate streams. if you don't like that, you'll have to use something else. trade lossless. you probably don't need it, and even if you think you want it, it might make no sense on the type of video you're compressing.

you should explicitly set the PTS from whatever's closest to the creation time of each frame. if None just goes by some FPS value, that would be bad. if it just took some current timestamp, that'd be fine.

It should also be noted/remembered that: 1. the Python GIL prevents proper concurrency; 2. showing all frames (and considering point 1) may affect overall performance, if the CPU can't keep up and; 3. you must decide how to trade between quality and performance (including both speed and size), with video you can rarely get both. About point 2, you should probably consider some frame dropping mechanism, possibly using a thread-safe object to share the last available frame(s).

Also, you mention using PyQt in the question title and tags, but your code actually uses PySide. While those bindings share similar purposes and behavior, they should quite carefully be considered as "completely identical", especially when dealing with multi-threading and specialized usage as yours. There are many cases for which the same code may behave differently using PyQt or PySide (also depending on the version of both Qt and/or Python binding), and you should clarify if your program aims to either one of those bindings or, possibly, both.
